# Adding percentage labels to ggplot when using stat_count

Tags: r, ggplot2

For some reason, I can't seem to be able to add correct proportion labels to a ggplot by using `stat_count`. The code below returns labels that display 100% for all categories, even though I'm using `..prop..`. Should I use something else instead of `stat_count`?

```
library(tidyverse)
diamonds %>% 
  ggplot(aes(color, fill=cut)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'fill') +
  stat_count(aes(label= scales::percent(..prop..)), 
             geom = 'text', position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5))
```

I know this can also be accomplished by calculating the percentage before feeding the data to `ggplot` (like below) but I have quite a bit of code which is using `geom_bar` and I would need to change all of it if I were to do it this way.

```
diamonds %>% 
  count(color, cut) %>% 
  group_by(color) %>% 
  mutate(pct=n/sum(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(color, pct, fill=cut)) +
  geom_col(position = 'fill') +
  geom_text(aes(label=scales::percent(pct)), position = position_fill(vjust=0.5))
```

Comment: which ggplot2 version are you using?

Comment: I just installed the latest `ggplot2` version but I still have the same issue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do the calculations within `geom_label()`, if you don't want to change the `geom_bar` part:

```
diamonds %>% 
  ggplot(aes(color, fill=cut)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'fill') +
  geom_text(data = . %>% 
              group_by(color, cut) %>%
              tally() %>%
              mutate(p = n / sum(n)) %>%
              ungroup(),
            aes(y = p, label = scales::percent(p)),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
            show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you, Z.Lin! Your solution works! Do you know why the default `..prop..` doesn't work (or what situations it was meant for)?

Comment: Based on my understanding, `..prop..` gives the **groupwise** proportion. By default `stat_count` considers each x-axis position separately, and `fill = cut` means each "cut" value (Fair / Good / etc.) is considered a distinct group. Thus each color-cut combination becomes its own group, with proportion = 100%.

Comment: Hey, great answer! Simple and understandable!